# I want to write a recursive query which can check for parentid, childid and return all the values with their grandchildren

Tags: sql, sql-server

That's the ids with me:

```
PARENT_ID   PROBLEM_TYPE_ID PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
12                1          Server/Hardware
NULL              2          IT General/Other
NULL              3           Phone/Voicemail
NULL              4                HR
10                5          CMS Applications
NULL              12         Incident (Technical Issues)
12                13          CMS Applications
```

thats the query i am using to calculate SLA and need to add one query to grab all the parent_id and childids so that I dont miss out on any tickets

```
SELECT 
  --[PROBLEM_TYPE].[PRIORITY_TYPE_ID]
  PROBLEM_TYPE.PARENT_ID
  ,[PROBLEM_TYPE].[PROBLEM_TYPE_ID]
  ,[PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME]
  ,[JOB_TICKET].[JOB_TICKET_ID]
  ,[JOB_TICKET].[REPORT_DATE]
,[JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE]
,[JOB_TICKET].CLOSE_DATE
,[JOB_TICKET].LAST_UPDATED
,[PRIORITY_TYPE].[PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME] AS 'Ticket_Priority',DATEDIFF(MINute, report_date,FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE) as 'time_to_accept', DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],[JOB_TICKET].[CLOSE_DATE]) as 'time_to_resolve',case WHEN DATEDIFF(MINute, report_date,FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE) <= 10 and DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],[JOB_TICKET].[CLOSE_DATE]) <= case PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME WHEN 'low' then 960 WHEN 'medium' then 480 WHEN 'high' then 120 WHEN 'Urgent' then 60 end then 1 else 0 end AS [SLA Compliant] FROM [SWHD01].[dbo].[PROBLEM_TYPE] INNER JOIN [SWHD01].[dbo].[Job_ticket] ON [problem_type].[PROBLEM_TYPE_ID] = [job_ticket].[PROBLEM_TYPE_ID] INNER JOIN [SWHD01].[dbo].[PRIORITY_TYPE] ON [PROBLEM_TYPE].[PRIORITY_TYPE_ID] = [PRIORITY_TYPE].[PRIORITY_TYPE_ID]where datediff(month, CLOSE_DATE, getdate()) <= 6 order by REPORT_DATE desc
```

thats the code I have and I need to incorporate your code with this one to get the correct job_ticket_ids and the output that i am expecting is given below @John Cappelletti

[image: Thats the expected output]

Comment: It is a good idea to give the table a name.  It is also a good idea to show the expected output — assuming that in the question is the input.  You should also show what you've tried.

Comment: hi @JonathanLeffler I have added my query in the answer below which I used to claculate SLA, I needed this query to find the job_ticket_ids which had child and grandchildren so that I grab all of the tickets for my SLA calculation. Just need help with incorporating this new query with mine as I am not that great with querying and have tried really hard.

Comment: PARENT_ID PROBLEM_TYPE_ID PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME JOB_TICKET_ID REPORT_DATE   CLOSE_DATE  time_to_accept time_to_resolve SLA Compliant
178    179   Monitor/Keyboard 142711   9/15/16 5:42 PM  9/15/16 7:15 PM  4    89    1
73    74   Access Issue/Error 142698   9/15/16 4:12 PM  9/15/16 4:16 PM  3    1    1
26    76   Monitor/Keyboard 142688   9/15/16 3:38 PM  9/15/16 4:04 PM  2    24    1
thats my output for my query and i need to make sure I grab all the tickets with child and grandchildren @JonathanLeffler

Comment: The auxilliary information should be added to the question, where it can be formatted properly.  Your 'answer' contains references to multiple tables for which there is no sample data in the question.  Your question cannot be answered; you've not made it coherent yet. You may need to transfer the information from your answer into your question. I've not spent the time working out whether your answer is an answer or a supplement to the question, but if it is a supplement, then you need to move the content to the question and delete the (not really an) 'answer' quickly before the down-votes hit.

Comment: Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Your question is too minimal to be complete.

Comment: Just FYI, tagging someone like @Sanky won't work unless they've commented on the thread before (so your message to gordonlinoff won't have gone through unless he previously commented here and has since deleted that comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your SLA_Compliant fields contains your business logic

```
-- Create some Base Ticket Data -- I trust your process will produce 
Declare @Ticket table (Job_ticketid int,JOB_PROBLEM_TYPE int, Report_Date Datetime,Close_Date DateTime,time_to_accept int,time_to_resolve int,SLA_Compliant bit)
Insert Into @Ticket values
(1002,527,'2016-09-15 5:42 PM','2016-09-15 7:15 PM',4,89,1),
(1003,528,'2016-09-15 4:12 PM','2016-09-15 4:16 PM',3, 1,1),
(1004,530,'2016-09-15 5:42 PM','2016-09-15 7:15 PM',4,89,1),
(1005,529,'2016-09-15 5:42 PM','2016-09-15 4:16 PM',3, 1,1),
(1006,241,'2016-09-15 5:42 PM','2016-09-15 4:16 PM',3, 1,0)


Declare @Table table (PARENT_ID int,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID int,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values 
(12  ,1 ,'Server/Hardware'),
(NULL,2 ,'IT General/Other'),
(NULL,3 ,'Phone/Voicemail'),
(NULL,4 ,'HR'),
(10  ,5 ,'CMS Applications'),
(NULL,12,'Incident (Technical Issues)'),
(12  ,13,'CMS Applications'),
(12  ,527,'Alerting'),
(527 ,528,'Interpreter Alerts Not Working'),
(527 ,530,'Nutanix Prism Alters Not Working'),
(527 ,529,'Orion Alerts Not Working'),
(12  ,241,'Call Processing Center')

Declare @Top  int = null             --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 12
Declare @Nest varchar(25) ='|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteHB (Seq,Path,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,PARENT_ID,Lvl,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as (
    Select  Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as varchar(500))
           ,Path = cast(PROBLEM_TYPE_ID as varchar(500))
           ,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
           ,PARENT_ID
           ,Lvl=1
           ,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME 
     From   @Table 
     Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(PARENT_ID,-1) else PROBLEM_TYPE_ID end
     Union  All
     Select Seq  = cast(concat(cteHB.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME)) as varchar(500))
           ,Path = cast(concat(cteHB.Path,'.',cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID) as varchar(500))
           ,cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
           ,cteCD.PARENT_ID,cteHB.Lvl+1
           ,cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME 
     From   @Table cteCD 
     Join   cteHB on cteCD.PARENT_ID = cteHB.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID)
    ,cteR1 as (Select Seq,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteHB)
    ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID )
    ,cteFinalHier as (
        Select B.R1  
              ,C.R2
              ,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
              ,A.PARENT_ID
              ,A.Lvl
              ,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
              ,A.Seq                                      -- < Included for Illustration
              ,A.Path                                     -- < Included for Illustration
         From cteHB A
         Join cteR1 B on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
         Join cteR2 C on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=C.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
    )
Select A.R1
      ,A.R2
      ,A.Lvl
      ,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
      ,Tickets           = Count(*)
      ,Ttl_Accept        = sum(time_to_accept)
      ,Ttl_Resolve       = sum(time_to_Resolve)
      ,Avg_Accept        = avg(time_to_accept)
      ,Avg_Resolve       = avg(time_to_Resolve)
      ,SLA_Compliant     = sum(case when SLA_Compliant=1 then 1 else 0 end)
      ,SLA_Non_Compliant = sum(case when SLA_Compliant=0 then 1 else 0 end)
      ,Percent_Compliant = cast((sum(case when SLA_Compliant=1 then 1 else 0 end)*100.0)/count(*) as money)
 From  cteFinalHier A
 Join  (Select _R1=B.R1,* from @Ticket A Join cteFinalHier B on (A.JOB_PROBLEM_TYPE=B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID)) B on B._R1 between A.R1 and A.R2
 Group By 
       A.R1
      ,A.R2
      ,A.Lvl
      ,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
 Order By R1
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: no it calculates the time for all the hours of a day and not specific business hours. the time_to_accept and time_to_resolve are not counted while taking into consideration the business hours. I need to calculate the percentage while considering all these factors like business hours which are between 4:30am to 10:30pm from mon-friday and 4:30am-5:30pm on saturday-saunday, bank holidays, time_to_accept <=10 minutes and time_to_resolve when 'low' then 960 minutes, 'medium' then 480,'high' then 120, 'Urgent' then 60. @JohnCappelletti

Comment: Also I cannot insert, update any information as I only have read only access to my database, if in case i need to create or update any tables. Your help is highly appriciated @JohnCappelletti

Comment: Hello Sir it would be really great if you can help me with this last one. @JohnCappelletti

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Table table (PARENT_ID int,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID int,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values 
(12  ,1 ,'Server/Hardware'),
(NULL,2 ,'IT General/Other'),
(NULL,3 ,'Phone/Voicemail'),
(NULL,4 ,'HR'),
(10  ,5 ,'CMS Applications'),
(NULL,12,'Incident (Technical Issues)'),
(12  ,13,'CMS Applications')

Declare @Top  int = null             --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 12
Declare @Nest varchar(25) ='|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteHB (Seq,Path,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,PARENT_ID,Lvl,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as (
    Select  Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as varchar(500))
           ,Path = cast(PROBLEM_TYPE_ID as varchar(500))
           ,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
           ,PARENT_ID
           ,Lvl=1
           ,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME 
     From   @Table 
     Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(PARENT_ID,-1) else PROBLEM_TYPE_ID end
     Union  All
     Select Seq  = cast(concat(cteHB.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME)) as varchar(500))
           ,Path = cast(concat(cteHB.Path,'.',cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID) as varchar(500))
           ,cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
           ,cteCD.PARENT_ID,cteHB.Lvl+1
           ,cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME 
     From   @Table cteCD 
     Join   cteHB on cteCD.PARENT_ID = cteHB.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID)
    ,cteR1 as (Select Seq,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteHB)
    ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID )
Select B.R1  
      ,C.R2
      ,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
      ,A.PARENT_ID
      ,A.Lvl
      ,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
      ,A.Seq                                      -- < Included for Illustration
      ,A.Path                                     -- < Included for Illustration
 From cteHB A
 Join cteR1 B on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
 Join cteR2 C on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=C.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
 Order By B.R1
```

Returns

[image]

> **Now, If you change @Top to say 12**

[image]

Comment: @Sanky Hope it helps.  Cheers

Comment: I need to return job_ticket_id in the below given manner and need only "Incidents","Service Request" and "Orion Alert" in my output so that I can calculate  the SLA for these ticket types                                                                      PARENT_ID PROBLEM_TYPE_ID PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME JOB_TICKET_ID REPORT_DATE CLOSE_DATE
178 179 Monitor/Keyboard 142711 42:28.0 15:19.0
73 74 Access Issue/Error 142698 12:48.0 16:17.0
26 76 Monitor/Keyboard 142688 38:40.0 04:03.0

Comment: I have posted my original query and the desired output in the question. please check and help @JohnCappelletti

Comment: I have edited the question and have added the expected output. Please help me thorugh this.

Comment: @Sanky The desired result is still not clear or formatted properly.  In other words... "Help me help your"

Comment: @Sanky Perhaps you can mock-up the results in Excel and post an image

Comment: I have uploaded an image of the expected output. Coudl you please check and let me know if this works and if you could help me out? @JohnCappelletti

Comment: @Sanky Looks promising.  On a call right now.   Will take a harder look in 30 minutes

Comment: sounds great sir @JohnCappelletti

Comment: @Sanky Added another answer

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell:

1. We create some dummy ticket data.  I trust your process will handle that
2. We create a dummy table from which we build the hierarchy
3. We Build the Hierarchy
4. Generate the final results

A couple of notes.  Not clear what the field name for Problem_Type in the Ticket table, so I named it JOB_PROBLEM_TYPE.  Also, if your hierarchy does not change often, you may want to store the hierarchy in a table (and rebuild as necessary).  This way, navigation is much faster and easier.  Further more, one can aggregate and summarize data as illustrated below.

---

--

```
Create some Base Ticket Data -- I trust your process will produce 
Declare @Ticket table (Job_ticketid int,JOB_PROBLEM_TYPE int, Report_Date Datetime,Close_Date DateTime,time_to_accept int,time_to_resolve int,SLA_Compliant int)
Insert Into @Ticket values
(1002,527,'2016-09-15 5:42 PM','2016-09-15 7:15 PM',4,89,1),
(1003,528,'2016-09-15 4:12 PM','2016-09-15 4:16 PM',3, 1,1),
(1004,530,'2016-09-15 5:42 PM','2016-09-15 7:15 PM',4,89,1),
(1005,529,'2016-09-15 5:42 PM','2016-09-15 4:16 PM',3, 1,1),
(1006,241,'2016-09-15 5:42 PM','2016-09-15 4:16 PM',3, 1,1)


Declare @Table table (PARENT_ID int,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID int,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values 
(12  ,1 ,'Server/Hardware'),
(NULL,2 ,'IT General/Other'),
(NULL,3 ,'Phone/Voicemail'),
(NULL,4 ,'HR'),
(10  ,5 ,'CMS Applications'),
(NULL,12,'Incident (Technical Issues)'),
(12  ,13,'CMS Applications'),
(12  ,527,'Alerting'),
(527 ,528,'Interpreter Alerts Not Working'),
(527 ,530,'Nutanix Prism Alters Not Working'),
(527 ,529,'Orion Alerts Not Working'),
(12  ,241,'Call Processing Center')

Declare @Top  int = null             --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 12
Declare @Nest varchar(25) ='|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteHB (Seq,Path,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,PARENT_ID,Lvl,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as (
    Select  Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as varchar(500))
           ,Path = cast(PROBLEM_TYPE_ID as varchar(500))
           ,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
           ,PARENT_ID
           ,Lvl=1
           ,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME 
     From   @Table 
     Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(PARENT_ID,-1) else PROBLEM_TYPE_ID end
     Union  All
     Select Seq  = cast(concat(cteHB.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME)) as varchar(500))
           ,Path = cast(concat(cteHB.Path,'.',cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID) as varchar(500))
           ,cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
           ,cteCD.PARENT_ID,cteHB.Lvl+1
           ,cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME 
     From   @Table cteCD 
     Join   cteHB on cteCD.PARENT_ID = cteHB.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID)
    ,cteR1 as (Select Seq,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteHB)
    ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID )
    ,cteFinalHier as (
        Select B.R1  
              ,C.R2
              ,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
              ,A.PARENT_ID
              ,A.Lvl
              ,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
              ,A.Seq                                      -- < Included for Illustration
              ,A.Path                                     -- < Included for Illustration
         From cteHB A
         Join cteR1 B on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
         Join cteR2 C on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=C.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
    )
Select A.Job_ticketid
      ,[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]=C.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
      ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] =B.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
      ,B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
      ,A.Report_Date
      ,A.Close_Date
      ,A.time_to_accept
      ,A.time_to_resolve
      ,A.SLA_Compliant
 From  @Ticket A
 Join  cteFinalHier B on A.JOB_PROBLEM_TYPE=B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
 Cross Apply (Select Top 1 * from cteFinalHier Where B.R1 between R1 and R2 and Lvl=1) C
 Order By B.R1
```

Returns

[image]

---

Here is an illustration of how you can aggregate data up the hierarchy

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @JohnCappelletti

Comment: hello sir i I am now able to run this query but needed one last thing from you. I want to count these number of tickets as percentage who meet the SLA. The SLA compliance is calculated if the tickets are accepted and resolved during the business hours which are between 4:30am to 10:30pm from mon-friday and 4:30am-5:30pm on saturday-saunday plus the bank holidays. Could you please help me on this? @JohnCappellett

Comment: @Sanky added another answer see column highlighted in yellow (image)